Solana Inner Instruction & Instruction Relationship
I am a beginner in Solana development. I just have a question regarding instruction and inner instruction.
https://solscan.io/tx/2FWNrPeZJ7XhgLHXHHeA6nnX68bkKh6TwZa3pGeHt7F9Nf4w29NAtLHYGjxA9dMWRiX1dYCeHF3WfaRJhFEvnXyh
If you look at this transaction #4 instruction. It runs the pump.fun program on chain. For its input account it has a bunch of account. Some of these account for example #1 seems to be generated by inner instruction #4.1.
My question is does #4.1 instruction come first or #4? Moreover, how do I replicate this transaction?

Hey did you end up getting a solution to this? I am assuming that the inner transactions are handled by the program as you would just give the accounts (keys), program Id and the data that will be used by the program.

So from my understanding solscan is displaying to you the token with the metadata (image tite etc) because it's already on-chain but at the time of when the transaction was sent the token mint was just a random generated public key so then that public key was passed into pump fun create instruction and then pump called system program in #4.1 to create an account but it was all just a random generated public key at that point meaning #4 was called which then invoked #4.1 and passed along the randomly generated public key (token mint) it was given. If you wanna learn more about this look into CPI
